# Не обрабатывается AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Почему-то не работает AJAX.

JS:
(вместо ip.ip.ip.ip стоит нормальный IPшник, конечно).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var validateStatus = $('#validateStatus');

      $('#status').blur(function() {
            var t = this; 
            validateStatus.removeClass('error').removeClass('success').html('<img src="/view/images/ajax.gif" height="16" width="16" /> update ...');

            var td = t.parentNode;
            var ID_of_TD = td.id;

            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://ip.ip.ip.ip/src/util/ajax.php',

              data: 'action=setStatus&status=' + t.value + '&id=' + ID_of_TD,
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'post',
              success: function (j) {
                if(j.ok){
                    validateStatus.html('<img src="http://ip.ip.ip.ip/view/images/accept.png"/>').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
                }
                else{
                    validateStatus.html('<img src="http://ip.ip.ip.ip/view/images/exclamation.png"/> '+j.msg).removeClass('success').addClass('error');
                }
              }
            });

         });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<td id="557144"><input type="text" id="status" name="status" maxlength="30" required /><span id="validateStatus"></span><br/></td>
```

PHP:

(1)

```
if (@$_REQUEST['action'] == 'setStatus' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    echo json_encode(setStatus($_REQUEST['status'], $dbh));
    exit;
}
```

(2)

```
function setStatus($id, $status, $dbh) {
  $response = array(); 
  $dao = new UserDao($dbh);

  if ($dao->setStatusUser($id, $status, $dbh)) {
    $response = array(
      'ok' => true, 
      'msg' => "");
  } else {
    $response = array(
      'ok' => false, 
      'msg' => "Wrong.");
  }
  return $response;        
}
```

(3)

```
    public function setStatusUser($id, $status){
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE `vk_users` SET `status`= :status WHERE `vkid`= :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
        $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
        $stmt->execute();

        $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
            return $count;
    }
```

Comment: Из мешанины кода ничего толком неясно, но одно понятно - политика безопасности запрещает создавать AJAX-запросы к другим доменам, поддоменам и другому порту. Поэтому... Use the hack, Valentina!

Comment: Этот тот же самый домен/IP. Мне просто неудобно писать без IP адреса.

Comment: И увеличить вероятность отказа чего-либо? Если обращение к этому же домену, лучше убрать абсолютный путь и юзать от корня `/path/to/file`.

Comment: @Valentina сидеть и гадать почему он не работает, конечно, можно, но разумнее добавить в Ajax запрос обработку ошибок: `error: function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown) { ... }` ([документация](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) и выяснить что именно не так.

Comment: @TheDoctor, сарказм конечно хорошо, но в вопросе код приведен и человек пытается разобраться в проблеме. Если и этот вопрос плох, то зачем SO вообще нужен?

Comment: @hardsky, Это ты про что?

Comment: @Valentina, Regent дело говорит, нужно посомтреть, что ajax в js возвращает и посмотреть отладчиком или логами, что на стороне сервера происходит.

Comment: @TheDoctor, это я про комент ваш, что "Из мешанины кода ничего толком неясно"

Comment: @hardsky, Ну это был не сарказм, а констатация факта. 80% просителей не умеют правильно спросить, иначе нашли бы ответ в гугле.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте полученный ответ обработать функцией `jQuery.parseJSON()` или задать заголовок у php-файла `header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

```
...
success: function (j) {
   var j = $.parseJSON(j);
   if(j.ok){
      validateStatus.html('<img src="http://ip.ip.ip.ip/view/images/accept.png"/>').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
   } else{
      validateStatus.html('<img src="http://ip.ip.ip.ip/view/images/exclamation.png"/> '+j.msg).removeClass('success').addClass('error');
   }
}
...
```